# Why can't I reach test.example.com from my browser, but ping in CLI can

Tags: linux, dns, browser, centos-7, hosts-file

I just want to test my CA engine from Hashicorp Vault. I've spinned up a local NGINX webserver in docker referring to `test.example.com`. Unfortunately I'm not able to reach it from my browser with that URL, but using `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` can. I edited the `/etc/hosts` file but that doesn't seem to work.

I tested it with `ping test.example.com` in CLI and it is successfully getting bytes from `localhost`. Also double checked it with the command `getent ahosts test.example.com`.

Afterwards I cleared the DNS cache by running the command `sudo service nscd restart` but nothing seems to work.

Somebody any ideas?

EDIT:
Also tried to add `*.example.com` in the IGNORE variable for the PROXY in `~/.profile`, but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

It seemed to be a proxy issue... `curl --noproxy '*' test.example.com` worked and I added the no proxy configuration in Firefox.